# How to create a new HTMLDocument in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, internet-explorer-8

[dcoument.implementation.createHTMLDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/html.html#HTML-DOM-createHTMLDocument) [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM) is one of the lesser-known DOM methods that (surprise!) creates a brand new HTML document.

Unsurprisingly, browser support is rather poor, but I found some workarounds:

- [Use an XLSTProcessor](https://gist.github.com/49453) (crazy stuff!) in Firefox < 4
- Create an empty iFrame:

  ```
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style = 'display: none';
  iframe.src = 'data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><title></title><body>';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  newHTMLDocument = iframe.contentDocument; // <- we need this.
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  ```

Still, since IE does not support the `data` scheme on iframes, there is no way to do it in IE. Or is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting `src` to `about:blank`?
(And perhaps `document.write`ing an empty HTML document)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried setting `src=about:blank`, but then `iframe.contentDocument == undefined` :( Could you be more specific about `document.write`?

Comment: Try setting `src="/404"`, then calling `contentDocument.write("<!DOCTYPE html><title></title><body")` to blank the document.

Comment: Also try `src="javascript:void(0)"`.

Comment: Actually `src=about:blank` works just fine, I just had some error in my wrapper function: While `var doc = iframe.contentDocument;document.body.removeChild(iframe);return doc;` is okay, this is not: `document.body.removeChild(iframe);return iframe.contentDocument;` Probably IE is too eager for clearing memory for once.

Comment: I have tried this and can't make it work: ``var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
doc = iframe.contentDocument;``. After this, ``doc.contentDocument`` is undefined.