# How to clone existing document in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a copy variable of `document` in `javascript`?

As I am a C# developer I want something like

```
var doc=new document();

    var doc = document;
    doc.open('application/txt', 'replace');
    doc.charset = 'utf-8';
    doc.write('Message to write in txt file');
    doc.close();
    if (doc.execCommand('SaveAs', true,'test.txt')) {
        alert(success);
    }
```

I have one button and some other controls in the iframe popup where i want to open saveas dialog onclick of button. After i run the above code 'Message to write in txt file' is showing in the page where i have my button and other controls

Comment: To "clone" a document, you could just load the same URL in another window. As for your `new document()` syntax requirement, I'm afraid it cannot be achieved in browser-embedded Javascript, since you cannot create a function named `document()` in that context (well, you *can* create it in non-strict mode, but you cannot call it).

Comment: It would be better if you can tell us what you are trying to achieve. It's nearly meaningless to create a copy of browser `document`

Comment: Is anybody have answer for this ?

Comment: it's a bit tricky, but it can be done. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935664/how-to-create-a-new-htmldocument-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue like below. I have added a iframe in my page and did the below.

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    var message = 'Message to write in txt file';           
    doc.open('application/txt', 'replace');
    doc.charset = 'utf-8';
    doc.write(message);
    doc.close();

    doc.execCommand('SaveAs', true, 'test.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clone method in JQuery http://api.jquery.com/clone/

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. When used in conjunction
>   with one of the insertion methods, .clone() is a convenient way to
>   duplicate elements on a page.

Comment: Note that the [DOM Level 2 Core W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4) says that `cloning Document, DocumentType, Entity, and Notation nodes is implementation dependent`.